# Failed to compile in the chrome browser in react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner in react js and also firebase. I am following a youtube tutorial where the author created an app that can post images, but it shows me an error in here.

```
  Line 10:  'collection' is not defined  no-undef      
  Line 20:  'unSub' is not defined       no-undef      
  Line 22:   'collection' is not defined  no-undef
```

And here is the code I'm following:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/Config';



const useFiresore = () => {
    const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
       const unsub = projectFirestore.collection(collection)
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .onsnapshot((snap) => {
            let documents = [];
            snap.forEach(doc => {
                documents.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
            });
             setDocs(documents);
        });

      return () => unSub();

    }, [collection])

    return { docs };
}

export default useFiresore;
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear; **'collection' is not defined** here -> `.collection(collection)`. What is `collection`? (not the function call, `collection()` but the `collection` var between the parentheses). And then the typo `unSub` upper case 'S' as the answer points out.

Answer (score 0):

from your code, you are obviously missing a collection definition. isn't it a parameter for useFiresore?
regarding unSub, it's a typo unsub vs unSub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).